# PureScript - Access Properties of a NewType

Tags: purescript

Consider the following code sample, which creates a new type to represent a customer model:

```
module Main where

import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console ( logShow )
import Prelude (Unit,(+),(/),(*),(-), (<>),discard)

newtype Customer 
  = Customer
  { firstname :: String
  }

sample :: Customer
sample = Customer
  { firstname : "Average"
  }

first :: Customer -> String
first a = _.firstname a

main = do
  logShow ( first sample )
```

The expected output would be the value `Average`, which is equal to `sample.name`, but instead an error is produced:

```
 Could not match type
  
    { firstname :: t0
    | t1
    }
  
  with type
  
    Customer
  

while checking that type Customer
  is at least as general as type { firstname :: t0
                                 | t1
                                 }
while checking that expression a
  has type { firstname :: t0
           | t1
           }
in value declaration first

where t0 is an unknown type
      t1 is an unknown type
```

This is a good error, but doesn't explain how to actually access this value.

How do you access the value of an object created as a newType?

Answer (score 3):

You have to do

```
first :: Customer -> String
first (Customer a) = _.firstname a
```

Since `newtype` is really, a new type.

Comment: Or diectly using record property: `first (Customer a) = a.firstname` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

One another way is to derive Newtype instance for that particular newtype, which exposes certain [functions](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-newtype/5.0.0/docs/Data.Newtype#t:Newtype) that will let you work on the data wrapped by the newtype.

```
derive instance newtypeCustomer :: Newtype Customer _
 
first :: Customer -> String
first  = (_.firstname <<< unwrap)
```

Comment: It is also possible to use `un Customer` instead of generic `unwrap` - pretty useful when you narrow the domain.

Comment: Yes, thats a good idea, when we want to narrow down the domain we could use `un` instead of the generic unwrap. Thanks man.